# Wordpress: Set input value as shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, shortcode

I'm using a plugin called USP Pro on Wordpress. I wanted to use the following code to post values from a previous form, but soon discovered that I cannot use PHP in the back-end editor on Wordpress for my input value:

```
<input name="usp-title" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST[titles]; ?>" />
```

As PHP is not supported in the editor, I created a shortcode instead called [input] which is for the above PHP snippet and set it to the value as seen below.

```
<input name="usp-title" type="text" value="[input]" />
```

In the front-end, however, the shortcode just appears in the input text box as [input]. Before creating the shortcode, I have tried using plugins to enable PHP to execute in the text editor but haven't been successful with those either. Also, I'd prefer to avoid creating a template and putting the code in (although it would solve my php issue) as it would mean I'd have to modify some of the plugin's code regarding php sessions, and I don't have the necessary skills as im new to php.  If anyone could help me come up with a solution to setting the input value to the PHP snippet I'd be very appreciative.

Here is what I put in to my functions.php for the PHP snippet as well.

```
function input_func( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'name' => '',
), $atts ) );

return '<input name="' . $name . '" id="' . $name . '" value="' .        
(isset($_POST['titles']) && $_POST['titles'] ? $_POST['titles'] : '') . '"        
type="' . $type . '" />';
}
add_shortcode( 'input', 'input_func' );
```

Thank you.

Comment: How are you using the short code and how is it appearing in the front end?

Comment: I'm using the shortcode as my input field value: '<input type="text" value="[input]" name="usp-title" />'   It appears in the front- end  simply as [input] within the text box input, rather than executing the php code it should represent that is <?php echo $_POST['titles']; ?>

Comment: You just need to use [input] in the editor, because your are already returning the HTML markup in the function